# Bulma icon not showing up?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am trying to use bulma icons following the docs [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/icon/), but the icon doesn't show up:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css">
 
 <div>
  <span class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
  </span>
  <span>ICON</span>
 </div>
```

Also see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wvpk1jtj/), what could be the problem?

Comment: `fa fa-home` looks like [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/), you need the css and font files. I am unaware if bulma uses that, but it would not surprise me.

Comment: @Theraot You are correct. Make sure you read the blurb about font awesome on the Bulma [getting started](https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/) page.

Comment: Ahh that's it. After including the font-awesome, it works now. Do you mind add the link to the answer @TPorter so I can accept it?

Comment: @TPorter Thanks for the link. What Psidom said, your answer is incomplete. It says in the link you posted that you need to include `font-awesome.min.css` separately. In fact, you can see in file [bulma.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css) that it does not link it nor contain the definitions for the icons. Edit: and thanks to the edit, it is now inaccurate too.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You also need to include the `bulma.min.css` file, not just the `.map`.

**Edit**

Per the [Bulma docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/):

> If you want to use icons with Bulma, don't forget to include Font Awesome:
>
> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

**Update 3/19/2019**

As @Akshay has pointed out below, the documentation has changed and the proper way to include Font Awesome is now

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: Above solution did not work for me, but based on Bulma Docs, I added `<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>` and it is working now!!!

Answer (score 3):

Bulma icons won't show up unless you call fontawesome libraries, we can use a kit code for that. This will look like `<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxxxxx.js"></script>` in the `<head>...</head>` section of your code.

note: you can get the code "xxxxxxxx" for free usage of fontawesome icons from the website.
https://fontawesome.com/start